# Comparing the growth rate of two functions using L'Hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

For the two functions $f(n)=n^{100}$ and $g(n)=2^{n/100}$, I am trying to determine whether $f(n) = O(g(n))$. In order to do this, I used L'Hopital's rule as if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0$, this implies that eventually $f(n) < g(n)$, and thus $f(n) = O(g(n))$.

As the following limit is of indeterminate form, L'Hopital's rule can be used:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \frac{\infty}{\infty}$$

However, when I tried using L'Hopital's rule using the derivatives of $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ with respect to $n$, the limit is of indeterminate form:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} {100n^{99}\over 2^{n/100-2}\cdot \ln2/25} = \frac{\infty}{\infty}$$

Is there any other method I can use to demonstrate the $f(n) = O(g(n))$, since using L'Hopital's rule did not work. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Notice that your limit is still in the indeterminate form $\infty / \infty$, and you can get your limit by repeatedly using L'Hopital.

Comment: So can I use it on the expression f''(n)/g''(n), and so on, until I get a definite answer?

Comment: If your limit is still in the form $\infty/\infty$ meets all the criterion for applying L'Hopital, you can use it as many times as you find necessary. So yes.

Comment: @ceno980.  Yes, 99 times.

Comment: I don't think L'Hopital's rule will be the best way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nor 
mally you shouldn't even think of L'Hospital? It is a basic result that for any $\alpha, \beta>0$, one has 
$$x^\alpha =o(\mathrm e^{\beta x}) \quad(x\to+\infty),\;\text{  which means }\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{x^\alpha}{\mathrm e^{\beta x}}=0.$$
Now, note that $2^{n/100}=\mathrm e^{\ln 2\cdot n/100}$.

Comment: What does o(e^βx) mean? Thanks.

Comment: It means what I wrote at the end of the equation.

Comment: What does the o in o(e^βx) specifically mean?

Comment: For me it's only a notation introduced  by Edmund Landau for a class of functions at the beginning of the 20th century. It reads as ‘little oh’.

Comment: Would it be possible to know how the above result was derived? E.g. Is there a proof for it?

Comment: It is a variation on the fundamental results (seen in high school):  $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac x{\mathrm e^x}=0$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x}=0$

Answer (score 0):

We have $\log\left(n^{100}\right)=100\log(n)$ and $\log\left(2^{n/100}\right)=\frac{\log(2)}{100}n$. Both of these tend to $\infty$. Applying L'Hopital to the logs gives
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{100\log(n)}{\frac{\log(2)}{100}n}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{100\frac1n}{\frac{\log(2)}{100}}\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Is the answer valid if you apply L'Hopital's rule to log(f(n)) and log(g(n))? I heard that when trying to demonstrate that f(n) is O(g(n)) you can't use the logs of f(n) and g(n) since f(n) ≠ log(f(n)).

Comment: If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}g(n)=\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(f(n))}{\log(g(n))}=0$, then for $n$ large enough, $\frac{\log(f(n))}{\log(g(n))}\le\frac12$, so $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\le\frac1{\sqrt{g(n)}}\to0$.

Comment: For the OP: the key requirement here for algebraic manipulation is that the inverse of $\log$ is non-decreasing. This gives a theorem more general than for just $\log$s.